# Quoting javascript object keys using a regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some key value pairs like this inside a string:

```
const process = 
`
abeezee: "ABeeZee",
abel: "Abel",
abhaya-libre: "Abhaya Libre",
`
```

I need to quote the keys such that the entire thing becomes valid json when wrapped with `{}`.  However not sure how to do this using a regex?

The end result needs to look like this:

```
"abeezee": "ABeeZee",
"abel": "Abel",
"abhaya-libre": "Abhaya Libre",
```

Comment: You need double quotes then, not single quotes. JSON strings (including object property names) must be delimited with double quotes. You also need an opening `{` and instead of a comma on the last line, a closing `}`

Comment: Indeed  - The regex part is what makes me break into a cold sweat ... :)

Comment: That end result isn't in valid JSON notation.

Comment: Try `(.+):\s*(\".*\"),` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RIciot/2/)

Comment: Pasted it in regex101, but looks like it's matching some of the values as well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need regex here, you can achieve that result using `Array.split`.

```js
const process = `abeezee: "ABeeZee",
abel: "Abel",
abhaya-libre: "Abhaya Libre"`;

const result = process.split(',\n')
  .map(line => {
    const [key, value] = line.split(':');
    return `'${key}':${value}`;
  })
  .join(',\n');

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this code snippet:

```js
const process = 
`
abeezee: "ABeeZee",
abel: "Abel",
abhaya-libre: "Abhaya Libre",
`

var jsonstr = '{' + process.replace(/^[^\s:]+/gm, '"$&"').replace(/,\s*$/, '\n') + '}';

console.log( jsonstr )

/* == Output ==
{
"abeezee": "ABeeZee",
"abel": "Abel",
"abhaya-libre": "Abhaya Libre"
}
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to trim the trailing comma and surround it with `{}` to have valid JSON:

```js
const process = 
`
abeezee: "ABeeZee",
abel: "Abel",
abhaya-libre: "Abhaya Libre",
`;

const json = '{\n' + process
  .replace(/^\s*|[\s,]*$/g,'') // trim trailing comma and leading/trailing whitespace
  .replace(/^/gm, '  "') // Add quotes at beginning of lines
  .replace(/^([^:]*):/gm, '$1":') // Add quotes before the first colon on each line
+ '\n}';

console.log( json );
```